# Convert nested if into switch

Tags: if-statement, nested, switch-statement

I would love to convert these nested if statement into a switch,
i am using finite state machine within these (switch cases) and each case has its own timing.
(working on avr related project.

original switch

```
for(i=1;i<17;i++)
  {
    Print_On_LCD_Pos(i,2," Humidity: 67%"); // just example
    Print_On_LCD_Pos((i-1),2," ");
    _delay_ms(600);

    if(i==16)
      {
        for(j=16;j>0;j--)
         {
           Print_On_LCD_Pos(j,2,"Humidity:67%");
           Print_On_LCD_Pos((j+13),2," ");
           _delay_ms(200);

           if(j==1)
             {
               Print_On_LCD_Pos(10,2,"             ");
               _delay_ms(400);
               Print_On_LCD_Pos(10,2,"67%");
               _delay_ms(400);
               Print_On_LCD_Pos(10,2,"             ");
               _delay_ms(400);
               Print_On_LCD_Pos(10,2,"67%");
               _delay_ms(400);
              }
           }
      }
    }
```

I was having a bit confusion as result as to how to keep in track of incremental/decremental variables without cases sharing data across. The dilemma here is that as you know for finite state machine they run in sequences so while case 1 run it might share some some data with another case unless I put some limitations ofcourses but these is going a lot like unnecessary long code.

Anyone to share a neat way of doing it?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Hi mate, it is c, the " Print_On_LCD_Pos(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, char * string_of_line) " is an LCD function i use to displays data on a 2x16 hex lcd.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
static uint16_t state = 0;

state++;

if ( state < 17 ) {

  const uint16_t i = state;

  Print_On_LCD_Pos(i,2," Humidity: 67%"); // just example
  Print_On_LCD_Pos((i-1),2," ");
  _delay_ms(600);

} else
if ( state < 32 ) {

  const uint16_t j = 16 - (32 - state);

  Print_On_LCD_Pos(j,2,"Humidity:67%");
  Print_On_LCD_Pos((j+13),2," ");
  _delay_ms(200);

} else 
if ( state == 32 ) {

  Print_On_LCD_Pos(10,2,"             ");
  _delay_ms(400);
  Print_On_LCD_Pos(10,2,"67%");
  _delay_ms(400);
  Print_On_LCD_Pos(10,2,"             ");
  _delay_ms(400);
  Print_On_LCD_Pos(10,2,"67%");
  _delay_ms(400);

} else {

  state = 0;

}
```

Expanding on that, maybe you could/should replace the `_delay_ms(...)` calls with more state transitions. Since all your delays are multiples of 200ms you could execute your state machine every 200ms, decrement some wait state counter, and immediately return if it's not 0. This frees up a lot of CPU resources and is actually the most common reason to build a state machine in the first place, besides C's absent features for light-weight concurrent programming.